# How to identify multiple level array object class type regardless of array level?

Tags: java

The 'doSomething(T[] obj)' method accepts any level of array type object, but unable to dynamically identify the object type regardless of array level.

Based on Test.java, The multiple level array of Integer and String objects are not executed correctly. It returns "doSomething(T[] obj) false" instead of "doSomething(T[] obj) true";

Test.java:

```
/*  
    Actual Output:
    Integer: doSomething(T obj) true
    Integer[]: doSomething(T[] obj) true
    Integer[][]: doSomething(T[] obj) false
    String: doSomething(T obj) true
    String[]: doSomething(T[] obj) true
    String[][]: doSomething(T[] obj) false

    Expected Output:
    Integer: doSomething(T obj) true
    Integer[]: doSomething(T[] obj) true
    Integer[][]: doSomething(T[] obj) true
    String: doSomething(T obj) true
    String[]: doSomething(T[] obj) true
    String[][]: doSomething(T[] obj) true
*/
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("0: " + doSomething(new Integer(1)));
        System.out.println("1: " + doSomething(new Integer[]{}));
        System.out.println("2: " + doSomething(new Integer[][]{}));

        System.out.println("0: " + doSomething(new String("")));
        System.out.println("1: " + doSomething(new String[]{}));
        System.out.println("2: " + doSomething(new String[][]{}));
    }

    public static <T> String doSomething(T obj) {

        if (Number.class.isInstance(obj)) {
            /*
             do something
             */
            return "doSomething(T obj) true";
        } else if (String.class.isInstance(obj)) {
            /*
             do something
             */
            return "doSomething(T obj) true";
        }

        return "doSomething(T obj) false";
    }

    public static <T> String doSomething(T[] obj) {

        if (Number[].class.isInstance(obj)) {
            /*
             do something regardless of array deep
             */
            return "doSomething(T[] obj) true";
        } else if (String[].class.isInstance(obj)) {
            /*
             do something regardless of array deep
             */
            return "doSomething(T[] obj) true";
        }

        return "doSomething(T[] obj) false";
    }
}
```

I would like it to be done dynamically instead of hard coded as below.

```
        if (Number[].class.isInstance(obj)) {
            /*
             do something
             */
            return "doSomething(T[] obj) true";
        } else if (Number[][].class.isInstance(obj)) {
            /*
             do something
             */
            return "doSomething(T[] obj) true";
        } else if (Number[][][].class.isInstance(obj)) {
        ...
```

We have no idea in future about the array level.

Comment: `String[][].class.isInstance(obj)` for 2 deep

Comment: @Ferrybig, I would like to do it dynamically, because I have no idea about the array level in the future.

Comment: Could you post a real working example and a sample input / output? What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Tunak I try to create a function to export the array as String. The Arrays.deepToString does the good job for array, but I'm too greedy to expect more than that. As an example (new String[][]{new String[]{"00", "01"}, new String[]{"10", "11"}}), The Arrays.deepToString returns [[00, 01], [10, 11]], but I expect [["00", "01"], ["10", "11"]].

Answer (score 3):

In both cases (#2) `Integer[][]` is not `Number[]` type (as `String[][]` is not `String[]`), so your program gives you correct result.

Why it so? Because actually `Integer[][]` type declares an array type which elements are of the type `Integer[]`, but itself it **isn't** `Integer[]`.

So, if you want to "catch" such things you have to add:

`} else if (Integer[][].class.isInstance(obj)) {`

and

`} else if (String[][].class.isInstance(obj)) {`

conditions, or just single `} else if (Object[][].class.isInstance(obj)) {`.

**UPDATE**: As you wrote in your comment, you want to be able to work with arrays of arbitrary dimension. In this case such idea can help you:

```
    } else if (Object[][].class.isInstance(obj)) {
        for (T[] subArray : (T[][])obj) {
            doSomething(subArray);
        }
        /*
         do something regardless of array deep
         */
        return "doSomething(T[] obj) true";
    }
```

Comment: I would like to do it dynamically, because I have no idea about the array level in the future.

Comment: This won't work with an empty array I believe, like `new Integer[0][][][]`.

Comment: `new Integer[0][][][]` is nonsense, it will never contains any data

Answer (score -1):

add this to your code:

```
public static <T> String doSomething(T[][] obj) {
    if (Number[][].class.isInstance(obj)) {
        return "doSomething(T[][] obj) true";
    } else if (String[][].class.isInstance(obj)) {
        return "doSomething(T[][] obj) true";
    }
    return "doSomething(T[][] obj) false";
}
```

Comment: I checked the code ... it works fine with the above code!

Comment: No, the problem is not in syntactical correctness. You didn't got the idea what does author want. He want be able to work with arbitrary dimension of arrays.